# How to mirror a p2 update site to my remote p2 update site?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho, p2

I have read this [article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#mirroring-a-p2-update-site-with-maven-tycho) about how to mirror a p2 update site to local, but how can I mirror a p2 update site (eg. `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-06` ) to one of my remote p2 update sites ?

By the way, are there any files required as a p2 update site?
I noticed that the contents of the mirror-to local repository were missing some files, such as p2.index, compared to the mirror-from remote p2 update site.

Comment: A mirrored p2 update site can be used locally or remotely. There are no differences. There must be at least an `artifacts.xml` and a `content.xml` that might also be provided compressed as `.jar` or `.xml.xz` (for backward compatibility a p2 repository should not only provided as `.xml.xz`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter whether your p2 update site is locally (accessed via `file://...`) or remotely (`http://...` or `https://...`). It's a folder structure that can be moved. So you can upload the directory of your to local mirrored p2 update site and vice versa.

A p2 repository must contain an `artifacts.xml` file and a `content.xml` file that might also be provided compressed as `.jar` and/or even more compressed as `.xml.xz` (assuming it's an artifact and a metadata repository in one and not separated, which is also possible). The `p2.index` file existing only for performance reasons. The best performance you will get with a `p2.index` plus an `artifacts.xml.xz` and a `content.xml.xz` file and for backward compatibility, an `artifacts.jar` file and a `content.jar` file in addition.

See [Eclipse Wiki: *What is the p2.index file?*](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/p2_index#What_is_the_p2.index_file.3F) for more details.

You can also have a [composite p2 repository](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_(new)).